# How to make Android Notifications even when the app is closed like any chat app

Tags: android, notifications, chat

I want  to make Android Notifications to show even when the app is closed like any chat app
i tried using this->

```
 fun createnotfictionchannel() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val name = "Title"
            val desc = "desc"
            val importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
            val channel = NotificationChannel("id", name, importance).apply {
                description = desc
            }
            val notificationManager : NotificationManager? = requireActivity().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager?
            notificationManager!!.createNotificationChannel(channel)
        }
    }
    fun sendNote(title:String, description:String){
        val pendingIntent: PendingIntent =
            Intent(requireContext(), MainActivity::class.java).let { notificationIntent ->
                PendingIntent.getActivity(requireContext(), 0, notificationIntent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)
            }
        val builder =
            NotificationCompat.Builder(requireContext())
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_notifications_24)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(description)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_MESSAGE)
                .setAutoCancel(true)



        with(NotificationManagerCompat.from(requireContext())){
            notify(1, builder.build())
        }



    }
```

But once the app is closed there isn't any notifications,
What can i use that has as little code possible?
Thanks

Comment: "But once the app is closed there isn't any notifications" -- that means whatever is calling this code is not running.

Comment: If you intend to send periodic notifications, use `WorkManager`.

Comment: Do you want to create local notification, or you want to fire a notification from backend, like when a message is received like a chat app?

Comment: @mohit48 yes ,i want to send message from backend like when a message is received like a chat app,

Comment: Then nothing can match the Firebase Cloud messaging: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging